# What makefile lazy evaluation rule governs this behavior?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to have a makefile variable for the content of a directory *after* that directory has been updated by a recipe.

**Why does this not work**:

```
A_FILE = $(wildcard subdir/*)

all: a
        @echo $(A_FILE)

a:
        @mkdir ./subdir
        @touch subdir/b
        @touch a
```

```
$ rm -rf ./subdir && make

$
```

...whereas this does:

```
A_FILE = $(wildcard subdir/*)

all: a
        @echo $(A_FILE)

a: subdir/b
        @touch a

subdir/b:
        @mkdir ./subdir
        @touch subdir/b
```

```
$ rm -rf ./subdir && make
subdir/b
$
```

?

I thought lazy-evaluation meant the variable was not evaluated until actually used. In both versions, `$(A_FILE)` is used in the same recipe, and after a prereq has been evaluated. In fact, I'd struggle to articulate a meaningful difference between the two rules, other than the superficial: the first is a chain of two rules/prereqs, and the second is a chain of three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also delete `a`:

```
$ rm -rf ./subdir a && make
```

Since you've deleted `subdir` but not `a`, the `a:` rule isn't triggered. Only this rule runs:

> ```
> all: a
>         @echo $(A_FILE)
> ```

And since `subdir` wasn't created, the `$(wildcard subdir/*)` expansion is empty.