# Is it possible to export a lazily-evaluated variable to a child Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, lazy-evaluation

This question is hopefully the last one I've been building up to from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084461/what-makefile-lazy-evaluation-rule-governs-this-behavior) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084643/why-does-makefile-lazy-evaluation-find-a-file-in-a-parent-recipe-but-not-the-c).

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── src
│   └── Makefile
└── test
    └── Makefile
```

My top-level Makefile just runs `$(MAKE)` on the `src/` and `test/` subdirs:

```
TOP_DIR := $(shell pwd)
export PRJ_LIBS = $(wildcard $(TOP_DIR)/build/*)

all: src test
        @echo $(PRJ_LIBS)

src:
        @$(MAKE) -C $@

test:
        @$(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: src test
```

My `src/` Makefile creates a file in peer subdirectory `build/`:

```
all:
        @mkdir -p ../build
        @touch ../build/libfoo.so
```

**I would like my `test/` Makefile to be able to access the updated content of the `build/` directory:**

```
all:
        @echo $(PRJ_LIBS)
```

---

The above Makefiles don't achieve this:

```
$ rm -rf ./build/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/test'

make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/test'

$
```

---

I figured out that one problem is that I was ***exporting*** `$(PRJ_LIBS)` in the top-level Makefile. Making this a non-exported variable improves things slightly: the updated content of the `build/` subdir is visible in the top-level Makefile's `all` recipe, but still not in the `test/` directory's Makefile:

```
...
#export PRJ_LIBS = $(wildcard $(TOP_DIR)/build/*)
PRJ_LIBS = $(wildcard $(TOP_DIR)/build/*)
...
```

```
$ rm -rf ./build/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/test'

make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/test'
/path/to/build/libfoo.so
```

By my amateur estimation, it looks like I have competing goals here: I want to "export" my lazily-evaluated variable so that it's "known" by both the top-level Makefile and a child Makefile, but exporting the variable seems to have the effect of immediate/up-front evaluation.

---

An apparent workaround is to rely on an explicit call to a shell command:

```
#export PRJ_LIBS = $(wildcard $(TOP_DIR)/build/*)
#PRJ_LIBS = $(wildcard $(TOP_DIR)/build/*)
export PRJ_LIBS = $(shell find $(TOP_DIR)/build -type f)
```

```
$ rm -rf ./build/ && make
find: ‘/path/to/build’: No such file or directory
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/test'
/path/to/build/libfoo.so
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/test'
/path/to/build/libfoo.so
$
```

Though this achieves my goal, exporting the variable has that unpleasant side-effect of the up-front evaluation resulting in the eyesore `find` failure to stderr. ***Not*** exporting the variable has the same effect as the second trial, above: the variable being evaluated as desired in the top-level `all` recipe, but not in the `test/` subdirectory's `all` recipe.

---

To someone more expert with Makefiles, **what is the best or "well-known" solution to what I'm trying to achieve: define a variable in a top-level Makefile that can be lazily-evaluated in a child-level Makefile?** Preferably with no side-effects like up-front shell command failures. (It's actually not important that the variable be evaluated in the top-level Makefile -- that was just more a debugging aid for me to understand things)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer one solution from the results of unguided experimentation:

I can ***not*** export my lazy variable in the top-level Makefile, and then pass it as an argument to the child make, like so:

```
TOP_DIR := $(shell pwd)
PRJ_LIBS = $(wildcard $(TOP_DIR)/build/*)

all: src test
        @echo $(PRJ_LIBS)

src:
        @$(MAKE) -C $@

test:
        @$(MAKE) PRJ_LIBS=$(PRJ_LIBS) -C $@

.PHONY: src test
```

```
$ rm -rf ./build/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/amenon/code/fubar/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/amenon/code/fubar/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/amenon/code/fubar/test'
/home/amenon/code/fubar/build/libfoo.so
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/amenon/code/fubar/test'
/home/amenon/code/fubar/build/libfoo.so
$
```

I'm curious what Makefile experts make of this solution -- is this considered a good way to solve this?